# How to set up git deployment to Staging and Production from BitBucket so they don't have working trees?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We have a repo that contains 'develop' and 'master' branches among others. I have it set up so that I push new commits from my machine to the develop branch. I am currently the only developer but expect to have more in the future. I create a branch on my machine for a new feature, do the development, commit and merge that branch to develop on my machine and then push to develop in the Bit Bucket repo. I then push the code to our Staging server. This is currently set up.

There will be no development on the Staging server so I don't need a working tree (do I?). I just want it simple - push the code to Staging and the changes are merged into the existing code. If some correction to the code in Staging is needed, that will be done in the original feature branch on my machine and committed, merged and and pushed to 'develop' on Bit Bucket and again pushed to Staging.

Likewise, once the code on the Staging server is verified, I need to merge the code into 'Master' from 'develop' in the Bit Bucket repo and push to the Production server from 'Master' in a similar manner as I'm pushing to Staging. All simple and clean. I'm not ready to get into automation of pushes with hooks just yet.

One glitch I have with this is that Production server code is an image from another machine and so it currently has a lot of "changes" both "modified" and "new" that aren't really changes, but old code. I successfully handled a similar situation on the Staging server using:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/develop
```

My main question is about the type of git instance I should have on the Staging and Production servers. Should they be bare? I think I have no use for a working tree since there will be no development on either server, but I don't know if a bare installation contains everything needed for a live server.

Note: This is a Laravel 8.41.0 framework with PHP 8.0.8 on Centos 8 machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the *opposite* of a bare repository: a bare repository contains *the git database* (version history), but no checked out code; what you want is *a particular snapshot of the code* (the working copy part of a git clone) but not the version history.

More fundamentally, your problem is that you are trying to use git as a deployment tool, which it is not designed for.

What you need is something which will take a release of the code from BitBucket, keep *just the code*, and deploy that to your server, *replacing any previous code*. You could script that entirely yourself, or you could make use of a CI tool like Jenkins, a deployment system like AWS CodeDeploy, etc.

However, if you want to stick with git-based deployment for now, here are the things to consider:

- Use a normal clone; a bare clone is no use, as explained above
- Use `git reset --hard` and `git clean -fd` to make sure the code is "clean" (but understand what they do first, don't blame me if they're not precisely right for you)
- Use `git pull -ff-only` to update the code, so that you'll get an error if you accidentally commit something in one of the "deployed" clones
- Make 110% sure that the `.git` directory is not accessible from the web, and there is no way for anyone to access its content

Comment: Thank you for your answer - what is the -fdr flag you included with git clean?

Comment: @DavidN It is actually three arguments shortened together (although I remembered one of them wrong, "-f" and "-d" are the ones I use). The arguments for all commands are documented [in the git manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean).